# Can I help Madanach and still become Thane of Markarth?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Can I help Madanach and still become Thane of Markarth?  I realize that these seem mutually exclusive, but I was wondering if you could gain/regain Jarl Igmund's trust.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That quest doesn't actually have an impact on whether you can become Thane or not. Speak to the jarl and he will likely give you a quest that will lead you to thanedom. You can see requirements for being a thane at [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Thane).

Comment: You are correct, it just took a while to prove.  Igmund would not give me the "Find Hrolfdir's Shield" until the civil war was over.